# How to Add a Dotfill for a TOC Chapter When There were None Earlier

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, dotfill

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  % Clears all blank pages
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}} % Space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{7pt}}  % Space after each Section 

\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % Turns off Chapter Page in TOC.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1---DESCRIPTION}
\section*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1 Title}

% NOW, I WOULD LIKE TO TURN ON CHAPTER PAGE # and ADD a DOTFILL in the TOC.
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%Turns chapter pg. numbers ON

% % % BUT---HOW TO ADD A DOTFILL?

\chapter*{2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 2---DESCRIPTION}
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

I have been able to add a page number beginning with the second chapter with the command `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add a TOC `dotfill` for the same second chapter---when there wasn't a dotfill previously.

QUESTION: How may I add a dotfill for the second chapter TOC entry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` to the preamble, a dotfill will be generated upon invoking `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}` to turn back on the page numbers.

Hence, with a couple of extra chapters added, the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  % Clears all blank pages
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}} % Space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{7pt}}  % Space after each Section 

\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % Turns off Chapter Page in TOC.

% TO ADD DOTFILL (BEGINNING) WITH CHAPTER 2.
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1---DESCRIPTION}
\section*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1 Title}

% TURN ON CHAPTER PAGE# (which "kicks in" the DOTFILL of the above \renewcommand)
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%Turns chapter pg. numbers ON

\chapter*{2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 2---DESCRIPTION}

\chapter*{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 3---DESCRIPTION}

\chapter*{4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 4---DESCRIPTION}
\end{document}
```

now produces the TOC:

[image]